# Carriage return as argument breaks the function

Tags: vimscript, functions

I have a remap that calls a function with a key combination as an argument. In this function I want to execute another remap to yet another function.
But whatever I do, it complains about a missing closing quote at the `iHello...` part. This seems to be happening inside `s:Test()`.

This also happens when I replace the literal carriage return (`^M`) with `<cr>`, or when I remove the `string()` function from the `s:Test()` function.

```
function! s:Test(obj)
    execute 'inoremap <silent> <tab> <esc>:<c-u>call <sid>Test2('.string(a:obj).')<cr>'
endfunction

function! s:Test2(obj)
    " do something
endfunction

nnoremap <localleader>a :call <sid>Test({'cmd':'Hello^MWorld'})<cr>
```

Comment: +1, I am also facing this issue. Replacing with ^M, <CR> didn't work

Comment: Did you tried giving different quotes like single quotes as the outermost and double quoted for innermost ones?

Comment: @SibiCoder sadly doesn't work. Also single quotes are already the most literal kind of quotation there is.

Comment: You can try `\r`, `\<CR>`, `<lt>CR>` as well

Comment: Too many levels of indirection, and objects to strings and back to objects. By this point you need to escape the ^M like so: 'Hello^V^V^V^V^V^V^V^V^V^V^MWorld'. Yep, ten ^Vs. Maybe you need to rethink your overall approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable, though quite complicated.  Here's how.

Step 1. Having `^M` in a mapping does not work, it is treated as if you hit `<CR>`, which would execute the `:call` command which is not yet complete.  To make it work we need to replace it with something which is not interpreted as an Enter hit -- e.g. `\n`:

```
nnoremap <localleader>a :call <sid>Test({'cmd':"Hello\nWorld"})<cr>
```

Note: the string has to be double-quoted, otherwise `\n` is treated as two characters instead of one `^M` character.

Step 2. `s:Test` tries to convert this to a string and pass on to another mapping command.  The mapping is successfully created, but when run -- has the same problem as in step 1 above -- object when converted to string has `^M` in it, which is treated as a `<cr>` hit, and executes the `:call` command.  This time we have no luxury of replacing with `\n`.  But we're within a function now and can do other tricks.  For example, we can now save this object to some script-variable:

```
let s:tab_argument = a:obj
```

This can now be used instead of `a:obj` in the mapping.  Also, since we don't have anything variable now, we can omit `execute` and define mapping directly:

```
inoremap <silent> <tab> <esc>:<c-u>call <sid>Test2(<sid>tab_argument)<cr>
```

Step 3.  Unfortunately, `:map` does not seem to be able to understand script-local variables.  Let's work around this by defining another function with no arguments:

```
function! s:tab_lambda()
  call s:Test2(s:tab_argument)
endfunction
```

Step 4. 
Now let's put this all together:

```
function! s:Test(obj)
    let s:tab_argument = a:obj
    function! s:tab_lambda()
        call s:Test2(s:tab_argument)
    endfunction
    inoremap <silent> <tab> <esc>:<c-u>call <sid>tab_lambda()<cr>
endfunction

function! s:Test2(obj)
    " do something
endfunction

nnoremap <localleader>a :call <sid>Test({'cmd':"Hello\nWorld"})<cr>
```

Note: I may be stating obvious, but make sure you don't have local `<tab>` mappings.  If you do, `inoremap` will succeed, but hitting `<tab>` won't call the `Test2` function.